# Unexpected behaviour when indexing vector with y[length(x) + 1:length(y)]

Tags: r, vector

I have a very specific problem, where I need to use the length of some shorter array, to subset a longer array. I have presented a toy example below. **I do not understand why it does not work to just add 1 when indexing, and I don't understand why it returns the long array filled with NA.**

```
x <- letters[1:5]
x
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
y <- letters[1:10]
y
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

y[length(x): length(y)]
# [1] "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
y[length(x) + 1: length(y)]
# [1] "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
y[(length(x) + 1): length(y)]
# [1] "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Using `y[length(x): length(y)]` almost solves my probem, but the resulting array is too long, I dont want to return 'e', I have to start from one more index to the right. I thought I could solve this by using `y[length(x) + 1: length(y)]`, but that gives me, for some reasons, a vector of the same length as y, and fills NA in the end. I found that using `(` solved the problem, but again, **I don't understand why, and what is happening when I don't use `(`**, if someone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

The colon operator comes before addition in the order of operations. Using the parentheses tells R that you want the value of `length + 1` as the first number in the sequence.

So, as you mention, the following should work:

```
y[(length(x) + 1): length(y)]
```